# Anyone know how to Typescript this, response?

Tags: typescript

I am not sure how to type this: This is generating a lot of errors.

```
// This seems all wrong as it just creating more errors
interface Response {
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  error: Error
}

/*
  // TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression 
    of type '"text" | "json"' can't be used to index type 'Response'.         Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Response'
*/ 
function parseResponse(response) {
  return response[response.status === 204 ? 'text' : 'json']();
}

function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response && response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }

  const error = new Error(response ? response.statusText : 'Offline');
  error.response = response; // TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type 'Error'.
  throw error;
}
```

ADDITIONAL BIT I AM HAVING ISSUE WITH?

```
export default function request(url: string, options = {}) {
  const requestOptions = {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
    },
 };

 const tokenAuth = authToken.getAuthToken();

 if (tokenAuth) {
   requestOptions.headers['Auth-Token'] = tokenAuth;
 }
```

SHOWS ERROR: TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"Auth-Token"' can't be used to index type '{ Accept: string; }'.   Property 'Auth-Token' does not exist on type '{ Accept: string; }'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response` is a type that already exists globally. You shouldn't have to define it all. Just use it:

```
function parseResponse(response: Response) { /* ... */ }
function checkStatus(response: Response) { /* ... */ }
```

---

For your second question, if you want to add a response to an error, then that property doesn't exist by default. You will probably want to subclass `Error`, add the property, and then instantiate that specific error class.

```
class ResponseError extends Error {
    response?: Response
}

function checkStatus(response: Response) {
  if (response && response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }

  const error = new ResponseError(response ? response.statusText : 'Offline');
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
}
```

Now you can catch that error and access the property by checking it's class first, so the compiler can be sure what type of error it is, and therefore that the response property exists:

```
// Catch the error
fetch('/').then(res => {
    try {
        checkStatus(res)
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof ResponseError) {
            // Can access the .response property on err here
            console.error("Error with response:", err.response)
        }
    }
})
```

[Playground with typesafe code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=28&ssc=3&pln=19&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmEAOB7AdheBRATjlO08AHgC7xoAmMu+hA3gFDQvQ6KobwD8AXHB3SZGAX0aMAZgFc0wUgEt00JGByYEyIfAAU7TV34bOmAJTQmLdqSk40bQVwDae4-AB0EUmGswAvP+gAJgAGABZobmgAcnIyKOh+KIArCHQogF1tEwBuUXFpWQUlYAALeGAAawBlLx9dB0xDBvgzC2h5CWh6-UxoADI++x73T28pGAA+XyDg4P7Bly0PWvHoAB5oAGZZ1uZWKxs7Ra5cljE94CFSIjwCaGm0eAB3AWHaAm7XCKHXZbGIAAqJGuiQA8hIJCB5I8ojk9vBbjg3MdetMUfBTtBSCV8C8EXRcucJPBSKVtFEAPSwtzYijde4Tcx7FikHAATyZrC50FK5WqKwg3RMzOgIh53lKXXxu25rA6Urw7QwXlk8BQnSMWneOBlsu5FIp0AAwmA7GBgMBEDBadBkc1lPgkAjSBylPjoGV2CK9TyhCgQO58R8AETa6BPeTYn5aXjBgA0NyR6OFPrEXLEIhMQA)

---

To get your third example to work, you probably just want to declare `headers` as a type that allows any string as a key. Then use that object in your request options.

```
const headers: { [name: string]: string } = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
}
const requestOptions = {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers,
}

requestOptions.headers['Auth-Token'] = 'abc123';
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=9&ssc=49&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgUwIYBMECcIC4YG8YDaYSAtgjtOgJZgDmAuhVNXTAL4wC8eAUDPzACCwYAgAOUHAHIkYsQBsqwJFCrgA9ACsI4KQBoebHqEix0CAI4BXBNADyEtZC68BMYObRhVSedhhSNMDyVmj6fAKIqBgQBkY85ta2UA6q4BAAdFFomARSglZQcAC0ACogANYIYFL0LjIARsAAjABMAMxSANxAA)

Comment: Can you see my addendum.. I added another item I'm having issues with, can you take a quick look? It's the headers bit. I tried to add the global Headers, but didn't work

Comment: Make that $200 and I'll think about it :) But upgrading legacy JS to typescript can be tough, especially when that code just randomly adds properties to things. I would not recommend learning typescript that way. Instead I would recommend starting a new project, building the types up as you go, and forcing yourself to never ever use `any` as a type for anything.

Comment: boss's orders.. update this codebase to typescript :-(

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the types a bit more, Typescript compiler is smart inferring the types from your code, but it needs some help:

```
function parseResponse(response:Response) {
  return response[response.status === 204 ? 'text' : 'json']();
}
```

You access the member "text" or "json" from response, which I assume has type Response. But the type Response does not have the members text or json. Since you are calling the expression I assume it must be some sort of function. This definition of the interface would make it compile (though I don't understand what the function might be):

```
interface Response {
    status: number;
    statusText: string;
    error: Error;
    text: ()=>string;
    json: ()=>string;
}
```

Note that of course extending the interface without actually offering any implementation for that function is not going to work at runtime

For the code :

```
   const error = new Error(response ? response.statusText : 'Offline');
   error.response = response; // TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type 'Error'.
   throw error;
```

You have to define the class Error otherwise the compiler will complain, that the Error class it knows does not have the member "response"

Comment: I thought there was a generic Error type?